# How to adjust text size from Java in Android

Tags: java, android, textview, text-size

I try to change my textview's size by using Java, not XML. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: [setWidth(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setWidth(int)) and setHeight..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview)).setTextSize(int);
```

Link to [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29).

Comment: Try using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int, float) and use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#COMPLEX_UNIT_SP